# Linux backup software (use backup2l?)

Tags: linux, backup, mysql, debian

Today I've set backing up most important files on my Debian Linux server with [backup2l](http://backup2l.sourceforge.net/) and a [Google Drive client](https://www.google.com/drive/download/).

But some files (MySQL dumps) are big and change often. This way I was unable to set many enough number of backup levels because space is limited.

So I consider to reconfigure the backup system to backup MySQL dumps and rest files separately (with different number of full backup and incremental backup levels).

However in backup2l for this it's required to create two separate conf files (one for MySQL dumps and another for the rest files).

Would you suggest me?

- use two conf files with backup2l and rewrite the cron scripts;
- switch to another (which?) backup software.